# How to literally translate this: 待油锅烫手时?

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

接下来，拿一个平底锅，先在锅里淋一圈油，待油锅烫手时，将切好的萝卜饼一块一块地放进锅里。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 19. I need help to get the literal translation of this clause: 待油锅烫手时.

待: does it mean to wait, to need or something else? How to make it make sense here?

油锅: does it mean pan or oil in pan?

烫手: I think it means to scald hand or to scald your hand

时: I think it means when or time, probably the easiest word here

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 待 XXXX 时 = wait until the time of XXXX
- 油锅 = frying pot/pan
- 烫手 (scalding hand) --> your hand can feel the heat from the pan

待油锅烫手时 = "wait until (you feel) the frying pan scalds your hand"

Don't put your hand in the pan, just feel the heat from the frying pan with your hand above it at a safe distance

[image: Frying pan]

Comment: I know it is ready when my face can feel the warmth from the pan